# 18.04 SSD freezes then file system sticks in read-only mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, filesystem, ssd, read-only

Since I put an SSD in my desktop i can't really use Ubuntu anymore. I have a Samsung SSD 860 and already tried using different versions of Ubuntu (18.04 LTS, 19.10, <strike>Pop_OS</strike>) but the problem keep happening. It's the fourth fresh install now and freezing started again, so i'll summarize what's happening.

After a fresh install everything works fine for some time (usually days) but after this period the system starts to freeze randomly and at some point after using the computer the file system goes to read-only mode and then the OS crashes, then on the next boot i needed to run a fsck to recover the system. I've collected some logs from syslog from when system crashed last time.

```
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:f0:40:9c:11/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 4096 in res 40/00:70:f0:9c:14/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/18:f8:50:9c:11/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 31 ncq dma 12288 in res 40/00:70:f0:9c:14/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1: hard resetting link
ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
scsi_io_completion_action: 28 callbacks suppressed
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 2d 11 9c 70 00 00 20 00
print_req_error: 28 callbacks suppressed
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 756128880 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 2d 11 9c 98 00 00 10 00
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 756128920 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
```

I don't think it is a problem with my SSD since everything is working fine on Windows 10. About my setup: [M5A97 PRO](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_PRO/specifications/), [AMD FX-8350](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/fx-8350) with 12 GB RAM.

Any help is welcome!

edit: As K7AAY and heynnema asked i'll post here my sudo lshw -C memory results:

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1604
       date: 10/16/2012
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 26
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 12GiB
       capabilities: ecc
       configuration: errordetection=multi-bit-ecc
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: Array1_PartNumber0
          vendor: Manufacturer0
          physical id: 0
          serial: SerNum0
          slot: DIMM0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0,9 ns)
          product: Array1_PartNumber1
          vendor: Manufacturer1
          physical id: 1
          serial: SerNum1
          slot: DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0,9 ns)
          product: Array1_PartNumber2
          vendor: Manufacturer2
          physical id: 2
          serial: SerNum2
          slot: DIMM2
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0,9 ns)
          product: Array1_PartNumber3
          vendor: Manufacturer3
          physical id: 3
          serial: SerNum3
          slot: DIMM3
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
```

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are welcome here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop OS forum.

Comment: You have NCQ errors. Before I recommend a fix, I need you to boot into Windows, download `Samsung Magician` (Google it), and check for firmware updates for your Samsung SSD. Also, have you installed any Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Report back.

Comment: @guiverc OP indicates that they even tried Pop_OS and got the same errors... not that they were currently running Pop_OS. Please consider reversing your VTC.

Comment: 12 GB RAM? Mix and match? Are the DIMMs all either single-rank or dual-rank? Are they spec'd at the same frequency?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema posted my memory info as you asked. Also, i already tried to check my ssd with Magician, and even run a full disk cleanup and i didn't installed any Windows drivers to read/write ext partittions... What are NCQ errors and why i don't have any problem running Windows ? thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**memory**

If memory is installed in matched pairs, memory interleaving can offer a speed advantage. However, you've got 4 memory slots, and only 3 slots are filled with 4G DIMMs each. It would be advantages, and inexpensive, to add one more 4G DIMM of equal specs to the current DIMMs, to realize these advantages.

**fsck**

Let's check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**NCQ**

In computing, **Native Command Queuing** is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

You're getting NCQ errors...

```
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:f0:40:9c:11/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 4096 in res 40/00:70:f0:9c:14/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
```

Since you've checked that the firmware in your Samsung 860 SSD is current, we can try and eliminate the NCQ errors this way...

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

Comment: I fixed the NCQ errors following your instructions and I've been monitoring syslog, so far no errors and the system seems stable, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @BrunoCesar Great news! Thanks for the update!

Comment: Samsung 840, 850 and 860 SSD drives seem to have firmware bugs that cause random freezes if NCQ is enabled. See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203475 for details.